# Excel VBA - How to insert comma after each word in a column

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column that contains multiple word strings. Like this:

```
+---+-------------------------------+--------------+-------------------------------+--------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
|   |               A               |       B      |               C               |       D      |               E               |               F               |
+---+-------------------------------+--------------+-------------------------------+--------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| 1 | Early Summer Lawn Application | Service Call | Early Summer Lawn Application | Grub Control | Early Summer Lawn Application | Early Summer Lawn Application |
+---+-------------------------------+--------------+-------------------------------+--------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
```

My question is how can I insert a comma after each word in the column, to end up with:

```
+---+-------------------------------+--------------+-------------------------------+--------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
|   |               A               |       B      |               C               |       D      |               E               |               F               |
+---+-------------------------------+--------------+-------------------------------+--------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| 1 | Early,Summer,Lawn,Application | Service,Call | Early,Summer,Lawn,Application | Grub,Control | Early,Summer,Lawn,Application | Early Summer Lawn Application |
+---+-------------------------------+--------------+-------------------------------+--------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
```

Its ok to lose the space between the words and its ok if the results are in a different column, I just don't know how to insert the commas.

Comment: cell F1 in your expected result has "Early Summer Lawn Application" should this not be "Early,Summer,Lawn,Application"?

Comment: You're right it should read "Early,Summer,Lawn,Application" I also screwed up my question but I'm not sure if it matters much. All of these are in the same column not in the same row.

Answer (score 3):

Won't a simple replace work here?

```
 =replace(A1," ", ",")
```

replaces space with comma. The other function is

```
=substitute(A1, " ", ",")
```

also works, but substitute has another argument that might come in handy. It specifies which occurrence to substitute. For example, if you only wanted to replace the first blank space with comma but leave other blank spaces as is, then try this:

```
=substitute(A1, " ", ",", 1)
```

Bottom line, use replace if you know where to replace (position), and use substitute if you know what to replace (content). Either would work for a narrow class of problems as you discovered.

Comment: Yes, wrapped in a loop for all rows.

Comment: I couldn't get replace to work, but it lead me to =SUBSTITUTE() which did. Thank you very much!

Comment: @user2942346 I updated the answer to explain the difference.

Answer (score 0):

The following example erplaces programmatically all spaces with commas:

```
Sub example()
Dim s1 As String, s2 As String
Dim pos As Integer
    s1 = ActiveSheet.ActiveCell.Value
    s2 = ""
    pos = InStr(1, s1, " ")
    While (pos <> 0)
        s2 = s2 & Mid(s1, 1, pos - 1) & ","
        s1 = Mid(s1, pos + 1)
        pos = InStr(1, s1, " ")
    Wend
    s2 = s2 & s1
    ActiveSheet.ActiveCell.Value = s2
End Sub
```